# How to export svg in matplotlib with correct mm scale

Tags: matplotlib, svg, export, scale, figure

I am trying to export a figure from matplotlib for laser cutting. The figure is plotted with millimeters as the units.

I'm tying to ensure the correct scale by getting the bounding box in inches and then setting the figure size to that value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111)

<snipped for brevity...plotting of lines and paths>

x_bound = map(mm_to_inch, ax.get_xbound())
y_bound = map(mm_to_inch, ax.get_ybound())
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(x_bound[1] - x_bound[0], y_bound[1] - y_bound[0])
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('{0}.svg'.format(self.name, format='svg'))
```

The exported .svg is ~2/3rds of the intended scale and I'm not familiar enough with axes and figures to know why. Additionally, there is a black border around the intended geometry. Here is some example output:
[.svg output (converted to .png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSlu0.png)

How should I remove the black border and scale the .svg correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to  remove the margins around the axes completely,

```
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
```

I might note however that the result may not be precise enough for the application. Definitely also consider creating the figure with a CAD program.

Comment: Thanks, sorry posted another answer!

Answer (score 0):

Based off of ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer and some responses to other stackoverflow questions, the following solution works:

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.margins(0, 0)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, right=1, left=0, hspace=0, wspace=0)

x_bound = map(mm_to_inch, self._ax.get_xbound())
y_bound = map(mm_to_inch, self._ax.get_ybound())
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(x_bound[1] - x_bound[0], y_bound[1] - y_bound[0])
```